# How to align button to center of listbox

Tags: html, css, listbox

I have two listbox where I am moving data of one box to another. Listbox I have are as below.

```
<select id="sourceCars" class="car" size="20" >
    <option>User 1 </option>
    <option>User 2 </option>
    <option>User 3 </option>
    <option>User 4 </option>
    <option>User 5 </option>
</select>

<input type="button" value=" >> " id="moveRight">
<input type="button" value=" << " id="moveLeft">
<select id="targetCars" class="car" size="20" >
</select>​
```

What I want is, take buttons  `>>` `<<` to the center of listbox and not at the bottom on the listbox.

Any idea how to get this done?

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yFxBc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input {
 position:relative;
 top:-150px;
```

}

Note that -150px should be replaced with half of the select height. Adding some class to those buttons will ease things up. For example:

```
.moveBtn {
  position:relative;
  top:-150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div class="butts">   
       <input type="button" value=" >> " id="moveRight">
       <input type="button" value=" >> " id="moveRight">
 </div>

.car{
    float:left;
}
.butts{
    margin-top:150px;
    width:70px;
    float:left;
}​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yFxBc/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Use position as absolute and then set left and top values.

See code here: http://jsfiddle.net/yFxBc/8/

Comment: be sure you don't use multiple id's on input

Comment: your code will work but its a bad design. I have so many textboxes before this list... all i see the button is at the top. Also never use px as you are not sure which desktop have what resolution...

Answer (score 0):

For set in center you use this css code

```
margin:0 auto;
width:250px;
```